# SQL Query Selecting Multiple Columns Using Distinct on One Column Only (different desired outcome)

Tags: mysql, distinct

There is a same title as mine, but the desired result is different, so please excuse my new thread.

In short, I wanted to select two columns from a table, and I wanted to remove duplicates from one column only.

But since it's input from multiple users, there are typos and different writing of their names, so I wanted to ignore the distinct names but want to use `DISTINCT` on the phone number, while also adding the country code.

I've checked and tried multiple sources.

I tried putting the `DISTINCT` on one column only, such as:

```sql
SELECT
    buyer_name,
    DISTINCT(concat('62', phone_number) as phone_number),
```

But it came as an error.

Then I got advised by my manager that I should put the `DISTINCT` beside the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    buyer_name,
    concat('62', phone_number) as phone_number,
```

But the typo names are still shown, therefore, duplicate numbers still happen.

**Sample data:**

```
buyer_name      phone_number
Doni            6281234567
sofia           6281234568
Sofia           6281234568
Sophia          6281234568
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
buyer_name      phone_number
Doni            6281234567
sofia           6281234568
```

Comment: You need aggregation rather than distinct. NB there is no way of knowing whether sofia or sophia is the correct name from the published data and question text.

Comment: Distinct is not a function, it is a modifier and works on the entire row in a resultset, not on individual columns. However, you have a bigger problem as you have the same phone number, but two different spellings (capitalisation differences are easy to ignore). You need to group by by the phone number and use min/max/any_value aggregate functions to return a name.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should come up with your desired result.

**DBFiddle link:** https://dbfiddle.uk/ctqwb-rC

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(buyer_name) AS buyer_name,
    phone_number
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    phone_number;
```